# Organizing complex data in R

Tags: r, sum

I have a very large data set. Roughly 300 columns, 500,000 rows. The data is tidy in the sense that there are no duplicates or unnecessary stuff. The columns can be meaningfully arranged in many different ways, meaning that I want to create, for instance, a sum of say, columns 5, 8, 10, and 15 in one case. But in another case, I want to sum columns 5, 8, 10, and 274. Creating a bunch of data frames for each such instance is obviously redundant. My current method of dealing with this is using arbitrary indices. For instance, calculating a sum by:

```
index <- c(5,8,10,274)
sum(df[index])
```

This works fine, but falls apart when one wants to compute a sum over many arbitrary indices. A list would also be redundant, because as far as I know, the data would have to repeat for every new way of summing it. Any suggestions for how this is supposed to be done?

This is my first question but I hope it's understandable without too much difficulty.

**edit**: Sometimes I need to use large indices, which makes numeric specification annoying. For instance: `index <- c(3,28,63,93,8,62,188,214,13,43,223,281,18,138,162,288,51,203,253,263,28,58,48,268)`. It's very tricky to know what these numbers refer to, so that's why it's also convenient to just write a name instead.

**edit2**:

```
    set.seed(123)
    df <- data.frame("A" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "B" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "C" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "D" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "E" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "F" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "G" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "H" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "I" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                     "J" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10))

# Suppose I want to sum over A, D, F, and J.
    meaningfulname1 <- c(1,4,6,10) #works fine
sum(df[meaningfulname1])
# Then a few more/other columns
    meaningfulname2 <- c(1,2,5,9,10) #works fine
    sum(df[meaningfulname2]) #both of these work fine, but how do I sum over both at the same time? E.g. below:

    lst <- list(meaningfulname1,meaningfulname2)    
    lapply(df[lst], sum) # doesn't work
```

Comment: just change ```lst <- list(meaningfulname1,meaningfulname2)``` to ```lst <- c(meaningfulname1,meaningfulname2)```

Comment: You're being super helpful and I'm realizing I'm not asking clear enough questions. Really sorry about that. The only difference now is that I mean independently (which was why I added lapply). So calculate the sum of meaningfulname1, and then for 2. Not together.

Comment: Alright, I think we're getting there.  Below is a for loop that will hopefully do what you need.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much! Now I just need to figure out how to approve the response appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("A" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "B" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "C" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "D" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "E" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "F" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "G" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "H" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "I" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10),
                 "J" = runif(1000, min = 1, max = 10))

meaningfulname1 <- c(1,4,6,10) #works fine
meaningfulname2 <- c(1,2,5,9,10) #works fine
lst <- list(meaningfulname1, meaningfulname2)    
sums_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(lst)){
sums_list <- c(sums_list, sum(df[lst[[i]]], na.rm = TRUE))     
}

names(sums_list) <- c("meaningfulname1", "meaningfulname2")

sums_list
$meaningfulname1
[1] 22054.61

$meaningfulname2
[1] 27259.2
```

Comment: Thanks! But I see now that I should have elaborated more. The problem is that I sometimes want to specify many variables, which makes enumeration a pain. This is why I use the arbitrary indices. And using colSums with arbitrary indices gives: "Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class list." Will update thread.

Comment: @gordonpennycook, I see your edit above, but I'm still confused.  If you want to use the column names rather than numbers you can, like I did with my "by name" example

Comment: if your columns have meaningful names that might inform the groupings you ar after you could use the tidyverse's select helper functions: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyselect/versions/1.0.0/topics/select_helpers to select groups of columns.

Comment: Is there a common substring inside the set of variable names you wish to select? In that case you could use colSums(df[, grep("yoursubstring", names(df)])

Comment: @Greg that only works if A and B are the names of the columns. What I need to do is find A and B using numeric vectors. I'll see if I can expand with a MWE.

Comment: @Richard J. Acton the columns don't have meaningful names, they're only i1 through i303.

Comment: @gordonpennycook do you mean like ```names(df)[c(1,4,5)]``` to get the names of columns 1, 4, and 5?